# Addition of elements of a list within a list

Tags: python-3.x

`[[6, 5], [4, 0]]`
This is the list within the list. I want to add the first elements,second elements and so on, i.e, 6+4,5+0,etc. How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: use `zip`:  `[sum(i) for i in zip(*arr)]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd unpack the list, zip it to get corresponding indexes together and then sum them:

```
lst = [[6, 5], [4, 0]]
result = [sum(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below sample code:

```
a = [[6,5],[4,3],[2,1]]

listSum = [0 for _ in range(len(a[0]))]
for i in range(len(a)):
 for j in range(len(a[0])):
  listSum[j] = listSum[j]+a[i][j]

print(listSum)
```